laravel take() returns empty collection for relationship
im trying to get 4 categories with only 4 articles in laravel using this code:
$categoryArticles = Category::whereHas('articles')->with(['articles' => function($q){
    $q->select('id', 'title')->take(4);
}])->take(4)->get();

but its returning empty artilces relation for some categories, the when i remove the take(4) in relation, the code will work correctly:
$categoryArticles = Category::whereHas('articles')->with(['articles' => function($q){
    $q->select('id', 'title');
}])->take(4)->get();

but i need to take only 4 article for each category.
what is the problem?
Article.php Model:
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'article_category');
}

Category.php Model:
public function articles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category');
}

article_category table:
    Schema::create('article_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


Your relationship is not properly defined.For Category.php it should be public function articles() {     return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category'); }.Can you please share your migration files for both of the Articles and Category model so that we can understand how these two model are connected based on  foreign_key?

@Subha they are not connected using foreinKey, they are connected using a pivot table (article_category) (many to many)

Are you sure you need many to many polymorphic relationship? I am asking this because based on the information you provided I assume you can do it using one-to-many relationship ? Even though you need many-to-many relationship we need to know what columns article_category table contains ?

@subha of course i need, each category has a lot of articles, and each article has multiple categories. now i edit my main question and add my article_category table info. take a look

Okay,got it. Tell me that does your article_id or category_id in article_category Table contains null or blank value for some of its record?

whereHas needs 2 parameters doesn't it? If you just want to check that it has the relationship you would use has

using take (LIMIT) inside a with Closure does not work. It won't load the first X related models for each Category. It will just load 4 articles in total.

@IGP depends on the Laravel version. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014 this has been solved on Laravel 11, before 11 you can use the package instead.

I was not aware this behavior had been corrected. That's quite nice
